# Migrate ProcessWire to WordPress

Tags: migration

Is it possible to migrate content from Processwire CMS to WordPress? If so, any ideas? Any tools?
I've spent a good amount of time researching but haven't found anything. I've opened the ProcessWire SQL database but the relations are quite complicated. Any suggestions?

Comment: First link in Google shows this: https://cms2cms.com/cms/supported-cms/processwire-to-wordpress-migration/ Have you tried it?

Comment: Landed here looking for the same. Any free tools or maybe even WP plugins to help with the migration? I have a custom script to get page names/slugs and parent/child hierarchy ready for WP but would love to know if there’s anything solid someone found.